# Why aren't my arrays updating as they should when I loop through an object? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to look through an array of objects and given the type property of a specific object, save that object in an array

If I have:

```
data = [
  {type: "recare", value: "Hello", ... },
  {type: "tocall", value: "World", ... },
  {type: "recare", value: "People", ...}
];
```

and this is my code :

```js
var recare = [];
var toCall = [];

data.map(function(k) {
  console.log(k.reason)
  if (k.type == 'recare') {
    recare[k] = k
    console.log("recare", recare)
  } else if (k.type == 'tocall') {
    toCall[k] = k
    console.log("tocall", toCall)
  }
});
```

I'm not sure why, but the objects aren't saving correctly as they should. Since there's more than one `recare` there should be both entries in the array but only the last one shows up I have What did I do incorrectly?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Please can you be more specific.

Comment: `.map()` returns a new array and is used to translate every element in an array. If you're only going to iterate over the elements of an array use `.forEach()`. You could also use `.filter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do like this `recare[k]` which means you are setting array key to object which is not valid, you can use `push` method of `Array` in order to insert data or use `i` of `map` function in order to `push` on same position as I was in original `array`

```js
var data = [
  {type: "recare", value: "Hello" },
  {type: "tocall", value: "World" },
  {type: "recare", value: "People"}
];
var recare = [];
var toCall = [];

 data.map(function(k,i) {
  if (k.type == 'recare') {
    recare.push(k);
  } else if (k.type == 'tocall') {
     toCall.push(k);
  }
});

console.log("recare ---------");
console.log(recare);
console.log("toCall---------");
console.log(toCall);
```

You have several other options You can use like forEach and filter

`forEach` and `for` loop is suites well for Arrays, In your use-case map is not for this type of work It looks same like forEach but use for in such a condition where you want to manipulating array and want back same array as result with modification

For like you have `Array`

```
var sample = ["a","b","c","d"];
```

and you want to `append` `"z"` in all `index`

```
sample  = sample.map(val=>(val+"z"));
```

result

```
["az","bz","cz","dz"]
```

filter will be the best choice which return same which you are looking

```
var recare = data.filter(function(k){ return k.type == "recare" });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: That's not the use-case `.map()` is made for.

Comment: @Andreas Yes I know!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value (`e`) to [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)'s callback function. Then check if whether `e.type` is equal to `recare` or `tocall` and [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the value to the correct array.

Here is a working code:

```js
const data = [
  {type: "recare", value: "Hello"},
  {type: "tocall", value: "World"},
  {type: "recare", value: "People"}
]

let recare = [];
let toCall = [];

data.map(e => {
  if(e.type == 'recare') {
    recare.push(e.value)
  } else if(e.type == 'tocall') {
    toCall.push(e.value)
  }
});

console.log(recare)
console.log(toCall)
```

---

You could also use a different data structure: for example, have the result be an object containing two arrays as values of the keys `recare` and `tocall`, as follows:

```
let result = {recare: [], tocall: []}
```

Then the map statement would be much shorter:

```
data.map(e => result[e.type].push(e.value));
```

```js
const data = [
  {type: "recare", value: "Hello"},
  {type: "tocall", value: "World"},
  {type: "recare", value: "People"}
]

let result = {recare: [], tocall: []}

data.map(e => result[e.type].push(e.value));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument passed to the map callback is the element not its index.
The arguments passed to map are in this order **data-element**, **index**, **array**.
And also your element is a object not a integer so thats why it can't be used as index.
You can use **push** method to insert elements at the end of desired array.

```
data.map(function(k){ 
       if (k.type =='recare') { 
           recare.push(k)
       } else if(k.type == 'tocall'){
             toCall.push(k)
       } });
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `recare[k] = k` to `recare.push(k)`

`k` is an object so you can't use it as an index.

Answer (score -1):

`if (k.type == 'recare') { 
    recare.push( k );
    console.log("recare", recare)
}`

This should get your objects pushed into the array at the end, giving you numeric indices on the array, which I believe is your intent.